# How to Filter by Debit or Credit in MongoDB using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

How can I get the List of Debit or Credit transactions Only. Like I have a column in my database , 2 columns actually.

I want to be able to query for Debit transactions or Credit , The endpoint is written in Node.Js and the backend is MongoDB

Suppose I am using MySQL (Just for you to understand , although i am using MongoDB ) I can run something like this

```
Select email, narration, credit , amount from narration where email = 'aa@gmail.com'
```

in MongoDB it is quite different. Please see the source code below, for a REST api

```
router.get("/get-credit-transaction/:email", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }
    const trans = await Transaction.find(
      { email: req.params.email },
      { email: true, narration: true, credit: true, amount: true }
    );
    res.status(200).json(trans);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

The same goes for Debit transactions

```
router.get("/get-debit-transaction/:email", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }
    const trans = await Transaction.find(
      { email: req.params.email },
      { email: true, narration: true, debit: true, amount: true }
    );
    res.status(200).json(trans);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

Saving the transaction done, I do it like so

```
const transactions = new Trans({
  email: email,
  narration: narration,
  credit: 0.0,
  debit: amount,
  amount: amount,
});
try {
  transactions.save();
  //res.send(savedUser);
  console.log("transaction saved");
} catch (err) {
  //res.status(400).send(err);
  console.log(err);
}
```

the above code is to save Debit transactions. Now back to the question, how do I get the list of transactions , be it Debit or Credit using Node.JS and the backend is MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should have a separate column, let's say `transactionType` denoting the type of the transaction `Credit` or `Debit`. In the current case, to search for debit transactions, you can apply a filter `where credit = 0.0` or vice-versa. Like this:

```
router.get("/get-debit-transaction/:email", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }
    const trans = await Transaction.find(
      { email: req.params.email, credit: 0.0  },
      { email: true, narration: true, debit: true, amount: true }
    );
    res.status(200).json(trans);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To shorten the code and get back the desired result. It will result for both debit and credit. Send type query param as `type=credit` or `type=debit` as shown in the following URL.

```
router.get("/get-transaction/:email?type=credit_or_debit", async (req, res) => {
  try {
      let transactionType = {};
      transactionType.email = 1;
      transactionType.narration = 1;
      transactionType.amount = 1;
      if(type == 'credit') {
       transactionType.credit = 1;
      } else {
       transactionType.debit = 1;
      }
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }
    const trans = await Transaction.find(
      { email: req.params.email },
      transactionType
    );
    res.status(200).json(trans);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```